# Why is it neceesary to add single quote inside the double quote in the bind command?

Tags: bash, double-quotes, single-quotes

I want to bind function key <kbd>f5</kbd>  with a play action ,when <kbd>f5</kbd> pressed ,the `sample.mp4` played by `ffplay`:

```
bind -x '"'$(tput kf5)'":"ffplay /tmp/sample.mp4"'
```

If write it as below:

```
bind -x '"$(tput kf5)":"ffplay /tmp/sample.mp4"'
```

The bind action can't take effect.

Why to add single quote inside double quote `"'$(tput kf5)'"` instead of `"$(tput kf5)"` ?

Comment: You are not adding single quote inside double quote. You are ending a single quote string and starting command substitution sequence.

Comment: Look at it this way: `'"' + $(tput kf5) + '":"ffplay /tmp/sample.mp4"'`. The shell does not expand anything in single quotes, so you need to take it out of the single quoted string. And you can't use double quotes directly because then you would need to escape the internal ones (this would be equivalent too: `"\"$(tput kf5)\":\"ffplay /tmp/sample.mp4\""`).

Comment: Try `echo` it out and you should see the differences. When in doubt about variable substitution, I always `echo` to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use here-doc to avoid quoting issues (or to have more readable code):

```
bind -x "$(cat << EOF
"$(tput kf5)":"ffplay /tmp/sample.mp4"
EOF
)"
```